Tracing iptables Rules
I'm just beginning to dig into iptables for the first time today, so apologies for any naivete.
For reference, I'm using

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables)
ufw 0.36.1

Now, I know (or, rather, recently learned) that ufw is just a wrapper for iptables. I decided I wanted to understand what was going on underneath the hood, so I started reading and poking around. What I can't seem to understand is how iptables deals with packets in conjunction with ufw. Let's start with the INPUT chain, which is I believe where any incoming packet would start.
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target                   prot opt source   destination
ufw-before-logging-input all  --  anywhere anywhere
ufw-before-input         all  --  anywhere anywhere
ufw-after-input          all  --  anywhere anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere anywhere
ufw-reject-input         all  --  anywhere anywhere
ufw-track-input          all  --  anywhere anywhere

I feel like if I'm understanding everything correctly, then this first line here ufw-before-logging-input all -- anywhere anywhere means that any packet that comes in, on any port, from anywhere, will be passed along to the ufw-before-logging-input chain. If it comes back from that chain without being accepted, dropped, or rejected, then it'll be passed on to the next chain, in this case ufw-before-input, and so on and so forth, until it's accepted, dropped, or rejected (viz., until it encounters a terminating action).
Okay, so let's look at the first chain any packet will be passed along to, ufw-before-logging-input.
Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Literally nothing here, so we move on to the ufw-before-input chain
Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target           prot opt source   destination
ACCEPT           all  --  anywhere anywhere
ACCEPT           all  --  anywhere anywhere     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny all  --  anywhere anywhere     ctstate INVALID
DROP             all  --  anywhere anywhere     ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT           udp  --  anywhere anywhere     udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local    all  --  anywhere anywhere
ACCEPT           udp  --  anywhere host.name    udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT           udp  --  anywhere w.x.y.z      udp dpt:num
ufw-user-input   all  --  anywhere anywhere

And this is where I'm confused. The very first line looks like we just accept any packet at all ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere but.... my firewall rules work, they block traffic.
So, what am I missing, here?
(Note, tried to post this on Stackoverflow, but they sent me here. Just including this in case you Google it and see this is duplicated elsewhere.)


So, what am I missing, here?

The -v option for verbose:

-v, --verbose
Verbose output. This option makes the list command show the
interface name, the rule options (if any), and the TOS masks. The
packet and byte counters are also listed,  [...]

You probably used something like:
# iptables -L  ufw-before-input
Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)  
target            prot  opt  source    destination                                        
ACCEPT            all   --   anywhere  anywhere                                           
ACCEPT            all   --   anywhere  anywhere         ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED      
ufw-logging-deny  all   --   anywhere  anywhere         ctstate INVALID                  
DROP              all   --   anywhere  anywhere         ctstate INVALID
[...]

which won't display interfaces. Instead with -v:
# iptables -v -L ufw-before-input
Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
pkts  bytes  target            prot  opt  in   out  source    destination                                        
   6    504  ACCEPT            all   --   lo   any  anywhere  anywhere                                           
  12   1032  ACCEPT            all   --   any  any  anywhere  anywhere         ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED      
   0      0  ufw-logging-deny  all   --   any  any  anywhere  anywhere         ctstate INVALID                  
   0      0  DROP              all   --   any  any  anywhere  anywhere         ctstate INVALID                  
[...]

One can see the ACCEPT rule is for input interface lo: to allow inconditionally loopback traffic, and only from the lo interface. Anything else continues chain traversal.
Anyway this format isn't really suitable for reproducibility especially when displaying a ruleset in a Q/A. It might still be useful to check status of special (eg: with memorized state) matches or targets. Better use either iptables -S or iptables-save (for the whole ruleset or at least a whole table).
# iptables -S ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-input
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
[...]

iptables -S can also accept the -v option to display counters among other states. Likewise to display counters with iptables-save use iptables-save -c. iptables-save is intended to provide an output suitable for iptables-restore allowing to save and restore rulesets. Also using twice -v (eg: -vv) with iptables displays additional debug information.

wow. I figured it was something small I was missing. Thank you so much!!
